# How to access an IMG URL that requires an authentication header with Angular-Meteor?

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I'm building an application using angular-meteor.  We log in via OAuth with a third party service.  Now I need to retrieve resources from that service, specifically images.  Unfortunately, a simple `<img src='...'>` isn't going to work; all calls must be authenticated with an `Authorization: Bearer ...` header.

How do I provide that header to the image calls?  I've considered using the server as a proxy (the obvious solution with a standard meteor app) but I can't figure out how to get Angular to pass the request through.

Edit:

For clarity, the issue is that with Angular handling the routing, I can't figure out how to define a route like `/photos/users/:id` that's handled by Meteor.  Angular sees that, detects it as a bad route, and redirects to route.

Comment: You will most likely have to proxy the requests yourself.  Setup a route to handle your resources (id use a set path with dynamic filename part to allow you to use one route for all resources), then open a connection using straight Node (HTTP/HTTPS or something like request/request module). Finally proxy the request/response over to get the resource passing the right header.

Comment: @CodeChimp I think you missed the point.  How do I add a route with Angular-Meteor that returns an image?  (For further clarity: the issue is that because Angular-Meteor is handling the routing all routes are handled by Angular.  'Somehow', magically, the /public folder is still available for direct fetch, but that's about it.)

Comment: I believe the way client-side URL routing works, in general, is that it tries to mitigate the URL entered client-side first, then falls back to the server second.  I say this not as an expert in how routing works, but only in my own observations in dealing with Meteor and server-side rendering.  Maybe take a look at [Picker](https://github.com/meteorhacks/picker/), which is a Meteor package I have used for server-side routing.  There may be others, but I have personally used that one to provide REST apis in a Meteor app.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem with Meteor, and ended up using cookies for a small part of the app as described here:

[Meteor: Endpoint for images fetched from S3 - How to authenticate connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41550192/angular-meteor-endpoint-for-images-fetched-from-s3-how-to-authenticate-connec/41566990#41566990)